# How to handle ASP.NET Session State in AppHarbor

Tags: asp.net, session, memcached, appharbor

As in any cloud platform as a service such as AppHarbor it is very important how to manage sessions because each user request can be handled by different server.

There are two ways:

- InProc if platform support sticky session, so user request always lands on the same server. Does AppHarbor support sticky session? I found some references that it does and some it doesn't.
- OutProc with Memcached as prefered solution which transfer session data between servers. Memcached is not supported in EU region. Why? There is third party AppHarbor Add-on but non build solution  managed by AppHarbor.

So what is recommended was to handle sessions (in EU region)?

Thank you very much for your help.

Marko

Some references:

- http://blog.appharbor.com/2011/08/29/application-scaling-now-in-beta
- http://support.appharbor.com/kb/tips-and-tricks/using-memcached-backed-sessionprovider

Comment: Good question I should say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use MemCachier for EU apps. The AppHarbor [support forums have details on how to get MemCachier set up for use with session state](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/22378-using-memcache-for-sessions-on-european-servers).

Comment: Thank you very much. It is strange that there is no out of the box solution for this. I do not think there are many applications that do not need session. It is strange that they do not support Memcached in EU. If they already have build solution for this, why not distribute in EU? But third party add on Memcachier looks OK and simple to use.